# Differences among James Stewarts's *Calculus* and *Calculus: Concepts and Context*?

Tags: calculus, education

Can anyone summarize the differences between James Stewart's *Calculus* and *Calculus: Concepts and Context*?

They appear nearly identical, though slightly arranged versions of exactly the same material, packaged differently (the former aimed down at the US-style high-school textbook market, and the latter aimed up a bit, perhaps at an older audience).

Note: I'm **NOT** asking for rants about the textbook business.

Comment: I've converted this to CW: the question phrasing "Can anyone explain the difference" is likely to lead to subjective description and evaluation. I also feel that this question may be a tad on the "too localised" side.

Comment: "Converted to CW"?

Comment: Frankly speaking, all Stewart's Calculus books look pretty much the same to me (I've been teaching from them since 1994) but everyone has to make his living in some way, hasn't he? On the other hand, if someone challenges you to write a principally novel exposition of calculus, will you be able to do it? I won't. IMHO, the question a potential calculus textbook writer faces today is "Which book to write?" rather than "What book to write?" If you ask because you want to know which Stewart's textbook would be better to read, my advice would be to read Spivak.

Comment: @rax: [community wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Comment: Innumerable authors write the same calculus text over and over again, with minor variations in the color of the figure on page 62, etc.  But the days when it's a startlingly bold and brilliant move to put the mean value theorem in section 4.2 instead of section 4.1 are past.

Comment: @Willie: Yes, I understand that, but to what end?

Comment: OK, I suppose I felling into "ranting about the textbook business".  But at least I kept that here in the comments.

Comment: I guess I sort of invited it by originally seeking an "explanation" for rather than a _description of_ the differences.

Comment: A personal anecdote: A friend of my parents was traveling in Europe, and, while in Paris, saw an old calculus book, written in French, which he purchased an brought home to me. As I recall, the book was written circa 1870. Other than that, the book looked remarkably like almost any other calculus book I have ever used, same topics, roughly the same order. So, I guess things haven't changed much over the years.

Comment: The subject matter was probably finished with Cauchy's Cours d'Analyse and notation probably since set theory became popular. If someone is bored he could arrange all calculus texts in some pedigree tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the preface to *Calculus: Concepts and Context* (4e), *Calculus* provides "fuller coverage of traditional calculus topics"; while according to *Calculus* (6e), *Calculus: Concepts and Context* "emphasizes conceptual understandings" with coverage that is "not encyclopedic and the material on transcendental functions and on parametric equations is woven throughout the book".